# If $\sum a_{n}$ is convergent then what about $\sum a_{n}^{2k+1}.$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $\sum a_{n}$ is a real  convergent series then what can we say about the convergence of the series  $\sum  a_{n}^{2k+1}$ i.e. odd power? It is convergent for positive term series. But what about any infinite series  $\sum a_{n}.$ I tried to find counterexample but did't got. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: comparison test.

Comment: @bartgol  is it convergent???

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/607293/show-a-convergent-series-sum-a-n-but-sum-a-np-is-not-convergent

Comment: My bad. I implicitly assumed $a_n$ to be, if not positive, at least alternating, in which case $\sum a_n^{2k+1}$ converges. But those are only particular cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not necessarily convergent.  In fact, any function $f$ such that $\sum_j f(a_j)$ converges whenever $\sum_j a_j$ converges must be linear in some neighbourhood of $0$.  See e.g. [this question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744674/if-sum-a-n-converges-then-sum-1n-frac-a-n1a-n2-converges).

Comment: what is counterexample?

Comment: But squares converges which are not linear in positive term series

Comment: @neelkanth You do **not** have $\sum_n a_n$ converges implies $\sum_n a_n^2$ converges. So the square function is not linear in any neighborhood indeed, but it does not satisfy the assumption either -- there is no contradiction.

Comment: @Robert Israel    No $\sum a_{n}^{2}$ is convergent if $\sum a_{n}$ for $a_{n}>0$

Comment: Yes, but the result stated above says "whenever $\sum_n a_n$ converges." There cannot be any restriction (e.g., positivity) on $a_n$:  again, it is not true that $\sum_n a_n^2$ converges for *all* $(a_n)_n$ such that $\sum_n a_n$ converges. It is only true under some further restriction on $(a_n)$, so the result above does not apply.

Comment: OK...But still i have no counterexample...

Comment: You didn't actually state you needed one (although it would be nice, yes): the answer above indeed does not provide one explicitly, but answers your question.

Comment: @ClementC.   if possible please one counterexample...thanks...

Comment: Take the sum $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} = (\sqrt{2}-1) \zeta(1/2)\approx -0.6$. It's square will not converge. I think for uneven exponents it should however be true but I am not sure

Comment: Have you read the linked posts (just below your question?)

Comment: @ClementC. Ah, I have now read http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96666/if-sum-1-inftya-n3-diverges-does-sum-1-inftya-n You are right this should be closed as a duplicate. The simple example is $\dots,\frac{1}{n^{1/3}},\frac{1}{n^{1/3}},-\frac{2}{n^{1/3}},\dots$ After cubing you get $\dots,\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n},-\frac{8}{n},\dots$ which diverges.

Comment: @ClementC. yes sir i got sufficient help...thanks a lot..