# Does the $\sum^{\infty}_{j=1}(b_j)^3$ converge if $\sum^{\infty}_{j=1}(b_j)$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If a series converges does the third power of the series converge? I want to say that if the terms of the series are all >0 then it does but if the series terms can be positive or negative I am not sure.

Comment: Third power applied on each term?

Comment: Does the $\sum^{\infty}_{j=1}(b_j)^3$ converge or diverge if $\sum^{\infty}_{j=1}(b_j)$ convereges? Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96666/if-sum-1-inftya-n3-diverges-does-sum-1-inftya-n

Comment: There is an edit button below your question. Please edit in the clarification so people see it easily.

Comment: I think that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ converges $\implies \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n=0\implies\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n^3$ converges.

Comment: @barakmanos No, see the link above. This is true if the $b_n$'s are non-negative, but not in general.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you say that if all terms are positive and they converge that the third power converges? I see that if we have negative terms there are counter examples.

Comment: @ryBear If all terms are non-negative (or positive a fortiori), then this becomes immediate by comparison. Then $b_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$, so for $n$ big enough, $b_n^2 < 1$ and $0 \leq b_n^3 \leq 1\cdot b_n$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$$1-2+1+1-2+1+1-2+1+\cdots$$ nearly converges, while

$$1-8+1+1-8+1+1-8+1+\cdots$$ not.

What if you divide every term by $\sqrt[3]n$ ?