# Convergence of $\sum a_n$ implies $\sum a_n/(1+|a_n|)$ is convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If $\sum a_n$ is convergent then is it true that  $\sum a_n/(1+|a_n|)$  convergent? If $a_n$ is positive term then we can easily prove this series is convergent by comparison test but how to proceed for general series?

Comment: How can we prove this easily if $a_n$ is positive?

Comment: Terms of series are less than $a_n$.

Answer (score 4):

No. A counterexample can be built following the ideas of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/96685/543769).

For positive integer $n$, let $a_{3n-2}=a_{3n-1}=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$ and $a_{3n}=-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$. Then $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=0$, but
$$\frac{a_{3n-2}}{1+|a_{3n-2}|}+\frac{a_{3n-1}}{1+|a_{3n-1}|}+\frac{a_{3n}}{1+|a_{3n}|}=\frac{1}{(1+\sqrt{n})(1+2\sqrt{n})},$$
thus $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{3N}a_n/(1+|a_n|)=\infty$ and this series diverges.