# If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ converges, then$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin(a_{n})$ also converges

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

If series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ converges, prove series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin(a_{n})$ converges  too.

Is this a series function problem or something related to?

I tried this:

If $a_{n} \ge 0 $ for all $n$, then $| \sin (a_{n})| \le a_{n}$, on the other hand $\sin(x)$ is continuous function in $[0,x]$ and differentiable in $(0,x)$ then exist $c \in (0,x)$ and 
$$(x-0)\cos (c)= \sin(x)-\sin(0)$$
then 
$$x\cos(c)= \sin(x)$$

but, $|\sin(x)|=|x\cos(c)|= |x| |\cos(c)| \le |x|$, thus $|\sin (x)| \le |x|$.

We know, $|\sin (a_{n})| \le |a_{n}| $ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ converges, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\sin(a_{n})|$ converges. Therefore $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin(a_{n})$ converges.

But this proof use ${a_{n}}$ positive and in the original problem I don't have this hypotesis.

Comment: I think you have a typo? Is it $\sin$ ?

Comment: Might just be a language issue. Some books written in other languages might write sen for sin. Anyways, Mari, can you show us any kind of working you may have done, as best as you can?

Comment: Is, by any chance, given that $\;\{a_n\}\;$ is a positve sequence (i.e., is the series a positive one?)

Comment: @AbhijeetVats yes, it was my mistake, my native language is spanish and I forgot the difference, I edit the post and add my work :)

Comment: ,@DonAntonio no, it's not, the problem just say that.

Comment: Without the non-negativity assumption, [the conclusion need not hold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116964/the-set-of-functions-which-map-convergent-series-to-convergent-series).

Comment: @DanielFischer: That surprised me! But the proof is not difficult.

Comment: It is trivial to see that if one takes $a_n=\frac{1}{n^{1/3}}, n=3k+1, a_n= -\frac{1}{2n^{1/3}}, n=3k+2, n=3k+3$, $\sum a_n$ converges, but $\sum \sin (a_n) \to -\infty$ as the $-x^3$ term in the taylor series dominates (the higher terms are absolutely convergent) and the linear term sums to a finite sum by construction

Comment: @DanielFischer It might be good to make your comment an answer, so that (1) it can be accepted to prevent the software form treating the question as unsolved and (2) people don't keep trying to prove the contrary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a "Community Wiki" answer recording a comment by Daniel Fischer under the question.  The comment provides a link [The set of functions which map convergent series to convergent series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116964/) to a proof that the result in question is false in general, though certainly true when the $a_n$ are non-negative. My reason for writing this answer is that comments can vanish more easily than answers and can probably also be more easily overlooked.

Comment: Neat. If I understand that proof properly, you can construct an explicit counterexample by considering the telescoping sum given by taking the triples $2/n, -1/n, -1/n$, repeating each such triple several times, and putting them all into a series. The $n$th triple should be repeated about $n^3$ times, corresponding to the nonlinearity $\sin(2x) - \sin(x) - \sin(x) \approx -x^3$.

Answer (score 5):

**If** $(a_n)_n$ is assumed non-negative (or non-positive), this follows from the comparison theorem as $0 \leq |\sin a_n| \leq a_n$.

**However**, the conclusion is false otherwise. Here is a counterexample: we are given in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/96685/75808) an explicit sequence $(a_n)_n$ such that

- $\sum_n a_n$ converges
- $\sum_n a_n^3$ diverges
- $\sum_n a_n^4$ converges (by inspection of the explicit sequence given)

Specifially: for all $n\geq 1$,
$$
a_{3n-2} = \frac{1}{n^{1/3}}, \quad a_{3n-1} = a_{3n} = -\frac{1}{2n^{1/3}}
$$

In particular, clearly, $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n =0$. Since $\sin x = x-\frac{x^3}{6} + O(x^4)$, we get
$$
\sum_n \sin(a_n) = \sum_n a_n -\frac{1}{6}\sum_n a_n^3 + O\left(\sum_n a_n^4\right)  
$$
(the use of $O(\cdot)$ here is OK, as we deal with an absolutely convergent series at that point). But $\sum_n a_n, \sum_n a_n^4$ are convergent (convergent and absolutely convergent, respectively), while $\sum_n a_n^3$ isn't: so the RHS diverges. So the LHS must diverge too.

Comment: Note: The only non-obvious part is the "(by inspection of the explicit sequence given)". But it is because in that explicit example, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^4 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{k^{4/3}}+ 2\cdot \frac{1}{2^4k^{4/3}}) < \infty$.

Answer (score -2):

Write $ \sum_n \sin(a_n) = \sum_n a_n + \sum_n a_n(\frac{\sin(a_n)-a_n}{a_n}) $. Since $ \sum_n a_n $ converges, $ \lim_n a_n = 0 $. Thus, for $ n $ large enough, by a Taylor series expansion, $ |\frac{\sin(a_n)-a_n}{a_n}| = O(a_n^2) $. Hence, by the triangle inequality, $ |\sum_n \sin(a_n)| \leq | \sum_n a_n | + O(\sum_n |a_n|^3) $. Finally, we use the fact that if $ a_n $ is nonnegative, then $ \sum_n |a_n|^3 $ converges whenever $ \sum_n a_n $ converges.

Comment: You make what seems to be a series of claims leading to a proof. Then you say that of course these claims are only valid if the $a_n$ are non-negative. So you lied! Can you at least tell us where your chain of inferences beaks down?

Comment: $ \sum_n a_n $ converges $ \implies $ $ \sum_n |a_n|^3 $ converges requires the $a_n$ to be nonnegative.

Comment: But if $a_n$ is non-negative, then $|\sin a_n|\leq a_n$ is enough to conclude...

Comment: True, though my solution shows that the conclusion is true for general $ a_n $ as long as $ \sum_n a_n $ and $ \sum_n |a_n|^3 $ both converge.